# How can I interpret correlation results?

Tags: matlab, statistics, correlation, p-value, pearson

I have some doubts about Pearson correlation in Matlab, especially in regard to the concept of p-value.
I have 2 vectors (A and B) and I computed Pearson correlation using `corrcoeff` function.
I have the following results:

Correlation

```
1   0.1219
0.1219  1
```

and relative p-value

```
1  0.3042
0.3042  1
```

What can I say about these 2 vectors?
I would say that they have low correlation for sure. But what about the p-value? (it's greater than 0.05)

Comment: Related: [Interpreting p-value significance from Pearson correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49113/interpreting-p-value-significance-from-pearson-correlation)

Answer (score 3):

The p-value is telling you that the correlation between the two variables measured in vectors A and B is not significantly different from 0 at a 0.3042 level.

What this p-value means is: if you conclude that the true (unknown) correlation between the variables is not 0, the probability of being wrong is 0.3042... which is usually interpreted as a large probability.
That's why, normally, such "high" p-values suggest that the analyst should NOT reject the hypothesis being tested (in this case the hypothesis is: "the correlation between the two analyzed variables is 0").

Answer (score 0):

The underlying null hypothesis here is that there is no linear relationship between A and B (i.e. the correlation between A and B is 0). A p-value of 0.3042, as you pointed out, is greater than 0.05. This means at the significance level of 0.05, we fail to reject the null hypothesis (i.e. there is no evidence to suggest that the correlation between A and B is significantly different from 0). This is expected considering that the correlation between A and B is quite low at 0.1219.